# Larger div centered inside smaller div

Tags: css

I have a div (`#containment`) inside another div (`#edit`).  The outer div is smaller.  The inner div's size will be changed by some jQuery code.

I want to make the inner div always centered inside of the outer div.

```
<div id="edit"><div id="containment"></div></div>

#edit {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:visible;
    margin-top:100px;
    background:gray;
}
#containment {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    opacity:0.5;
    background:red
}
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzAge/)

How can I do this?

Comment: Is `#containment` always 500x500?

Comment: edit div is always 200x200 containment will change depend user's image

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fzAge/4/)

```
#containment{
    width:500px; height:500px; opacity:0.5;  background:red;
    position : absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

By using `transform`, you're not dependent of the width and height from the parent container.
See [**caniuse**](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform) for browser support.

The properties `left` and `top` are setting the top-left-edge of the element to the center of the parent. By using `translate`, it shifts the X- and Y-Position back by 50 percent of its own dimensions.

You can find more information about `transform` on [**developer.mozilla.org - transform**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

Comment: Very nice. I wasn't aware of this new CSS3 property!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can do that.

```
#edit{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:visible;
    margin:200px 0 0 200px;
    background:gray;
    position : relative;
}
#containment{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    opacity:0.5;
    background:red;
    position : absolute;
    top : -150px;
    left : -150px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fzAge/2/

Comment: position : absolute; move edit div position, is anyway not affect parent div?

Comment: Any absolute positioned element is always relative to it's offset parent. Offset Parent is the element which has a position value other than the default one - static. Just to make sure that the containment div is relative to the edit div I added some margin to the edit div.

Answer (score 2):

The child `<div>` should have the following CSS properties

```
position: relative;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -250px; /* -(width/2) */
top: 50%;
margin-top: -250px; /* -(height/2) */
```

So if you're changing the child div via jQuery then you must re-calculate the margins...

### JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gvee/fzAge/5/

### Initialised CSS

```
#edit
{
    overflow: hidden;
}

#containment
{
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/500/500);
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    margin-top: -250px;
}
```

### JQuery

```
$('#edit').click(function() {
    var newWidth  = 100 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
    var newHeight = 100 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
    // Resize the child div
    $('#containment').width(newWidth).height(newHeight);

    // Let's assign a new background too, eh!
    $('#containment').css({'background-image': 'url(http://placekitten.com/' + newWidth + '/' + newHeight + ')'});

    // Now re-calculate the margins...
    var newLeftMargin = (newWidth  / -2);
    var newTopMargin  = (newHeight / -2);
    $('#containment').css({'margin-left': newLeftMargin, 'margin-top': newTopMargin});
});
```

Comment: The child div will change in size, so this doesn't apply.

Comment: I was only illustrating the theory. I will update my answer with the jQuery-ness now.

Comment: `margin-left: -250px; /* because the child is always 500px and will never change */` When will we scourge the planet of hard-coded sizes like this? Almost any time I write a hard-coded size, I will have to come back to it and change it to something flexible to make the site responsive. "The child div will change in size" shouldn't have to be said. By default, elements change in size (even though for the sake of minimum examples, we slap `width` and `height` on things). Elements NOT changing in size is the special case!