# How to center a child div with a smaller parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a div (fixed) which acts like a pop up:

```
<body>
    <div class="popup-container">
        <div class="popup-item">
            Yolowing
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This css allows the container to be horizontally centered (having a 100% width makes everything behind it unclickable; thus, I set it to 1px):

```
.popup-container {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.popup-item {
    display: block;
    min-width: 20px;
    padding: 25px 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

However, I am unable to center `.popup-item` due to the parent element `.popup-container` being smaller than its child. How do I center `.popup-item` while **still** being able to click it (`pointer-events: none` entirely disabled it)?

Comment: The answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082108/larger-div-centered-inside-smaller-div is most likely more helpful than this question's answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vote to Close almost has it, but with the 1px width, the element doesn't get centered.

Do this instead:

```
.popup-container {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-align:center;
    height:0px;
}

.popup-item {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 20px;
    padding: 25px 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

This will make it centered, because the container is 100% wide. However, `pointer-events:none;` will allow you to click through to anything below it.

Comment: what's the point of pointer-events, element has no background it is not suppose to catch anything . If more than one inline-block ement, tthey will stand aside each other :)

Comment: @GCyrillus why not test it out and see? As the OP stated, if it has a 100% width everything under it is unclickable. Look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/5BHhY/) to see why pointer-events:none; is necessary.

Comment: I know what is the purpose and use of pointer-events, i do think here it will cure the problem only in younger browser, he is better set height to 0 or 1 px to avoid this. overflow ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus Fair point. I updated my answer to use a 0 `height` instead, didn't think of that.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being to include something: What if I need to click something (like a link) in the ```.popup-item```. Won't ```pointer-events: none``` entirely kill it?

Comment: ```pointer-events: visible``` on ```.popup-item``` fixes this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of solutions.

First, you can make the child of the container centered using translateX() transform: http://jsfiddle.net/Yjz5R/.  The same effect can be accomplished using negative margins, but the width for the container's child has to be set: http://jsfiddle.net/9Qmza/.

CSS:

```
.popup-item {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 20px;
    padding: 25px 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Or second, you can make the container "immune" to click events:

Markup:

```
<input type = "checkbox" id = "clickToggle" />
<label for = "clickToggle">Click me</label>
<div class="popup-container">
    <div class="popup-item">
        Yolowing
    </div>
</div>
```

Styles: http://jsfiddle.net/CVfHt/.

```
.popup-container {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
    pointer-events: none;
}

.popup-item {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 20px;
    padding: 25px 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    pointer-events: all;
}

input[type = "checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type = "checkbox"] + label {
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type = "checkbox"]:checked ~ div {
    display: none;
}
```

Lastly, a question/comment.  If you do not want the container to be visible, then why use it at all?  Just keep the markup of the child and get rid of the container: http://jsfiddle.net/yvc4E/.

Answer (score -1):

```
.popup-container {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto; /* remove this line - unnecessary*/
    margin-right: auto; /* and this line, remove */
    width: 1px;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-align: center; /* add this */
}

.popup-item {
    display: inline-block; /* change to inline-block */
    min-width: 20px;
    padding: 25px 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```